# Table with column names that contains spaces does not work with the Filter function in Power Apps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I have a power apps that is using a sharepoint table where one of the columns contains a space, like this: 'Project Name'. Using my filter function (see below), I'm able to return rows from the table if I change the column name (and my filter function) to not contain any spaces like this: 'ProjectName'. I've tried to encapsulate the column name in the filter function both with single- as well as with double- quote marks, but still does not work.

This function returns rows when I use the 'mySearchTextBox' field to search for rows that starts with a given text (using table column names without space, in this case 'ProjectName'):

```
SortByColumns(
    Filter(
        [@'myTable']; 
        StartsWith(ProjectName; Text(mySearchTextBox.Text))
    )
    ; "Title"
    ; If(SortDescending1; Descending; Ascending)
)
```

However, when changing the table column name to contain spaces, in this case 'Project Name', and without quote marks in the filter function, this does not return any rows:

```
SortByColumns(
    Filter(
        [@'myTable']; 
        StartsWith(Project Name; Text(mySearchTextBox.Text))
    )
    ; "Title"
    ; If(SortDescending1; Descending; Ascending)
)
```

Nor this (encapsulating the table column name in single quote mark):

```
SortByColumns(
    Filter(
        [@'myTable']; 
        StartsWith('Project Name'; Text(mySearchTextBox.Text))
    )
    ; "Title"
    ; If(SortDescending1; Descending; Ascending)
)
```

Nor this (encapsulating the column name in double quote mark):

```
SortByColumns(
    Filter(
        [@'myTable']; 
        StartsWith("Project Name"; Text(mySearchTextBox.Text))
    )
    ; "Title"
    ; If(SortDescending1; Descending; Ascending)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once a column is created in a Sharepoint List, you cannot change its *internal name*. PowerApps uses this internal name. In order to solve this, you need to create a new column.

**Example:**

- From the Sharepoint List, click the Gear Icon then `List Settings`
- Select the column in question
- Look at the URL
- You should see that the internal name has a space in it
- Even though you change the *display name* of the column, you can't change the *internal name*

**Update:**

- It looks like Sharepoint finally fixed the default behavior
- Now, if you create a column name with a space in it, Sharepoint will remove the space
- It used to stick that URL encoded placeholder (what was it, `%x02` or the like)
- If its an older Sharepoint List, this is likely the case.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else that struggles with the same problem. What finally worked for us was: From sharepoint click on the table, go to 'List Settings' | 'Advanced Settings' | 'List experience' and change the value to 'New' instead of 'Default' (as it was in our table).